Nextjs update API endpoint and update REST APIs
I am not familiar with React, I just can use simple hooks.
I am trying to implement a dynamic URL REST API wrapper,
But I have no idea how can I update the API function.
My idea is:

Get API endpoint by localStorage value (it will be set from the previous page)
Update API address so the component can use it
Component will use the updated API and render

How can I achieve the goal?
Here are example codes:
// Component
"use client";

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import useMyApi from "./useMyApi";

export default function MyComponent() {
    const { getUserDataById } = useMyApi();
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        async function getData() {
            const userData = await getUserDataById(`some_id`);
            setUserData(userData);
        }
        getData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                { userData.name }
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

// API Wrapper
"use client";

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { apiEndPoint } from "./useApiEndPoint"

const useMyApi = () => {
    /**
     * How I can change api URL dynamically and how I set the function dynamically
     * Following useState argument not works because it has "id" parameter
     */
    const [getUserDataById, setGetUserDataById] = useState((id) => { })

    useEffect(() => {
        setGetUserDataById(async (id) => {

            const response = await fetch(`${apiEndPoint}/user/${id}`);
            return await response.json();
        })
    }, [apiEndPoint]);

    return {
        getUserDataById
    }
}

export default useMyApi;

// API Endpoint setter`enter code here`
// Address will be set by localStorage value
"use client";

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useApiEndPoint = () => {

    const [apiEndPoint, setApiEndPoint] = useState(``)

    useEffect(() => {
        const staging = localStorage.getItem(`staging`);
        setApiEndPoint(`https://${staging}-other-api-server.com/`);
    }, []);


    return {
        apiEndPoint
    }
}

export default useApiEndPoint;



in Next.js, there is a [...slug] type which can receive and show pages dynamically.

can not return apiEndPoint direct .. You have to use "props" method to send data.

@Park Are you trying to get user details by ID, & set user data in page ?
